# Controlling Number of Application Executions

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk

Is there a way to control the number of times an iPhone app executes.  For example, I have a game called widget and I only want the user to play the game (new instance) no more that 20.  Also, if tis is possible, how would you be able to stop the person from deleting then downloading the app again to get another 10 plays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not allowed to create time-limited demos on App Store. Apple won't let you. The usual solution is to create a "lite" version without all the content (levels in a game, features in an app).

Comment: This is a good idea.  It also prevents people hacking around the time limit.  If the content ain't there, they can't hack it.

Answer (score 0):

Short of forcing the application to authenticate with a server at each launch (which would be bloody annoying), you can't.

Comment: Especially annoying if internet access isn't available (highly likely on an iPod touch).

Answer (score 0):

You could put a little ticket into the keychain, but Apple probably wouldn't like that and that might trigger removal or rejection from the app store.